# How can I use IO methods (e.g. Console.Write, StreamWriter, etc..) in IEnumerable.Select?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("By ForEach : ");
        Enumerable.Range(0, 5).ToList().ForEach(i => { Console.Write(i); });
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("By Select : ");
        Enumerable.Range(0, 5).ToList().Select(i => { Console.Write(i); return i; });
        Console.WriteLine("");
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter("out.txt"))
        {
            sw.Write("By ForEach : ");
            Enumerable.Range(0, 5).ToList().ForEach(i => { sw.Write(i); });
            sw.WriteLine("");
            sw.Write("By Select : ");
            Enumerable.Range(0, 5).ToList().Select(i => { sw.Write(i); return i; });
            sw.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

By running this, I got the result below in both Console and out.txt. :

```
By ForEach : 01234
By Select :
```

Points I want to know are:

- Where the outputs of Console.Write and Streamwriter.Write went?
- Is there general solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: Related reading: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where the outputs of `Console.Write` and `Streamwriter.Write` went?

`ForEach` executes the delegate passed in immediately. `.Select` just creates a *query* whose execution is deferred until you actually *iterate* over it.  You would see the output if you added a `ToList` at the end of the `Select`:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 5).ToList().Select(i => { Console.Write(i); return i; }).ToList();
```

**However** - Linq is *not* meant to be used to execute code that has side-effects.  The fact that you're having to call `ToList` just so you can call `ForEach` indicates that you are not using the right tool for what you want to do.  If all you want to do is output the numbers just use a traditional `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(int i in Enumerable.Range(0, 5))
{
    Console.Write(i); 
}
```

`Select` is meant to take a collection and *transform* or *project* it to a *new* collection.  It is *not* meant to replace traditional `foreach` loops where you want to perform some *action* based on the input.

Comment: That said, as long as he's writing this monstrosity, he could just use `ForEach` after the first `ToList` and save himself the dummy return value and the second `ToList()`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Agree wholeheartedly - I was just adding that to the answer.